# indexoutofboundsexception when updating mutableStateListOf

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am making an app using compose in which I am using `LazyVerticalGrid` but when I update `MutableStateListOf` data it throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. If I use `if (index < arrayList.size)` everything works fine but I am still getting this exception from some of my users.

This is the simplified structure of my code.

```
val loading = mutableStateOf(false)
val arrayList = mutableStateListOf<String>()

fun loadData() {
  coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    loading.value = true
    arrayList.clear()
    arrayList.addAll(getData())
    loading.value = false
  }
}

if (loading.value == true) {
  // Loading Placeholder
} else {
  if (arrayList.isEmpty()) {
    // Empty Placeholder
  } else {
    LazyVerticalGrid() {
      items(arrayList.size) { index ->
        // if (index < arrayList.size)
        ItemLayout(arrayList[index]) // This line throw exception
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit :-**

Replacing `mutableStateListOf` with `arrayListOf` has solved my problem.

Comment: shouldn't it be `items(arrayList.size-1)` ?

Comment: Prefer using the other overload of `items` which accepts a list of items. Then you won't have you worry about indices.

Comment: @vincrichaud No, It's the right syntax.

Comment: @ArpitShukla, Already tried both methods but getting same exception.

Comment: @PorushManjhi This exception shows the total size of array and the index you are accessing in the output. What are those values?

Comment: @ArpitShukla, I am getting "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 0, size: 0". I think compose recompose after "arrayList.clear()" is called but it should be composing loading layout at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itemsIndexed` instead like this:

```
   itemsIndexed(arrayList) { index, item ->
          ItemLayout(item)
     }
```

Comment: Already tried, Not working.